# How to send a form after being immediatly validated with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

i'm having an issue with a form.
My issue is that i validate my form onSubmit, but in case the form would be valid, i need to click a second time on the submit button in order to send it (here reaching the console.log on the bottom of the file).

What could be possibly wrong here and how to fix it ? Or any other solution would be welcome.

Thank you in advance.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const letterRegex = /^[\w'\-,.][^0-9_!¡?÷?¿/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$/;

function App() {
  const [fullnameValue, setFullnameValue] = useState("");
  const [fullnameHasError, setFullnameHasError] = useState({ state: null, message: "" });

  let formIsValid = false;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFullnameValue(event.target.value);
  };

  if (fullnameHasError.state === false) {
    formIsValid = true;
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    //VALIDATION STATE MUST BE FALSE
    if (fullnameValue.trim().length === 0) {
      setFullnameHasError({ state: true, message: "Can't be empty" });
      return;
    } else {
      letterRegex.test(fullnameValue)
        ? setFullnameHasError({ state: false, message: "" })
        : setFullnameHasError({ state: true, message: "WRONG FORMAT" });
    }


    if (!formIsValid) return;

    console.log("YOUR FORM IS SENT");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={fullnameValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      {fullnameHasError.state && <p>{fullnameHasError.message}</p>}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have a look at react's own tutorial on forms: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

Only do `event.preventDefault()` if you don't want your form to submit. As it is, it's always preventing submission.

Comment: preventDefault() only prevent the form to reload the page, not to submit the form